# Create unique id in getDefaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component's `getDefaultProps` I'm returning an object like `{ id: idGenerator.unique() }` which should give me a unique id on each method call. However, react does not execute the `getDefaultProps()` method per instance, but only once for the component. So I end up with the same *not-so-unique* id whenever I use the component.

Is there an alternative to hook the id into the props object of each instance?

Comment: Does it need to be a prop? Are you going to be passing id in sometimes? Otherwise it may make sense as state

Comment: Well, it would be nice to be a default prop so that I can easily override it when I want to supply a custom id. If that is not going to work I will accept different approaches as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State from props is normally an antipattern, but may make sense here, eg:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
       return {
           id: this.props.id || idGenerator.unique()
       }
   }
   .....
});
```

And just use this.state.id instead of props. If the component is likely to get an ID at some point, you could handle that in componentWillReceiveProps